# Match and Replace a column with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I need to replace the column 13 of file 2, with the column 2 of file 1, when column 1 of file 1 matches with col 2 of file 2.

file 1

```
AAAA00000687697 HPNMS
AAAA00000693037 GER112
AAAA00000349750 FRA0158
```

file 2

```
585     AAAA00000687697 1    +       11868   14409   14409   14409   3       11868,12612,13220,      12227,12721,14409,      0       BBBB00000223972 none    none    -1,-1,-1,
585     AAAA00000693037 1    +       11871   14412   14412   14412   3       11871,12612,13224,      12227,12721,14412,      0       BBBB00000223972 none    none    -1,-1,-1,
585     AAAA00000349750 1    +       11873   14409   14409   14409   4       11873,12594,13402,13660,        12227,12721,13655,14409,        0       BBBB00000223972 none    none    -1,-1,-1,-1,
```

Output should be like

```
585     AAAA00000687697 1    +       11868   14409   14409   14409   3       11868,12612,13220,      12227,12721,14409,      0       HPNMS           none    none    -1,-1,-1,
585     AAAA00000693037 1    +       11871   14412   14412   14412   3       11871,12612,13224,      12227,12721,14412,      0       GER112          none    none    -1,-1,-1,
585     AAAA00000349750 1    +       11873   14409   14409   14409   4       11873,12594,13402,13660,        12227,12721,13655,14409,        0       FRA0158 none    none    -1,-1,-1,-1,
```

I tried the codes below

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} $2 in a {$13=a[$1];print}' FS='\t' OFS='\t' file1.txt file2.txt  > output.txt
```

It prints the file 2, with an empty $13 th column.

When I tried to print a[$1] alone, it prints an empty file; and when I remove the ;next part in first curly brackets it then can print only the a[$1]. I don't know why it has some troubles saving the array.

Comment: With `$2 in a {$13=a[$1]...` you're testing for **$2** being an index of a[] and then using **$1** as the index in a[] to get the new value from. Think about that for a second.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `$13` with the array string `a[$2]` if available:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}($2 in a){$13=a[$2]}1' file1 file2
```

Comment: Exactly, but the above code still does not work

Comment: @cookiemonster What isn't working exactly? Is there data missing? Is it column formatting? Please be more explicit.

Comment: I cannot be explicit because I don't know what is wrong, there is no data missing or anything. The output file is exactly the same as the input (file 2). When I change the command to { print a[$2] }, it does not print anything maybe why it cannot change the column.

Comment: *that's why it cannot change the column

Comment: @cookiemonster What is your version of awk? On what system are you running the command?

Comment: i guess awk 3.1.7